# how do I hide parent row when child rows expanded?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a data set that consists of the gross dollar amount on row 1, 1-n number of rows of various details then a last row  that shows the gross dollars minus the various row amounts. I am trying to replicate some expand/collapse functionality used in an internal ASP report page where the initial row is the NET value (collapsed). When expanded, the gross, detail, and net rows show up in a "expand up" action.

I have been able to so far get the parent row to show the NET values when collapsed, but I am trying to find a way to hide the contents of the parent row once expanded so that the NET values are not displayed twice.

Is there some kind of "is hidden" property I can use in an expression to hide the data in the cells? not sure how else I can accomplish this. Any help would be appreciated.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of that might help is `inscope()`. You can use something along the lines of:

```
iif(inscope("ChildGroup") = TRUE ...
```

This will test to see if the current item is within the scope of the grouping, which means that you can test if the current group is expanded or collapsed.

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156490(v=sql.100).aspx for more information on inscope().

Answer (score 0):

so after much research it appears this cannot be done thanks to SSRS producing a static report once rendered. The inscope function allowed me to set the initial state of the row, but does not give functionality to update report properties after rendering occurs. my only options would be then to create a second parent group (grand parent?) or insert an action that calls the report over again passing in a hidden parameter. 
thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this, but you'll need to make some adjustments.
A. You can't put your gross dollar amount in the row you'll be using to expand/collapse.
B. Don't use group visibility to expand/collapse.  You'll need to use row visibility.  (This can get tricky and I don't recommend it if you have nested groups.  It becomes unmanageable.)

Row 1: Toggle
Row 2: Gross Dollar Amount, default visible
Row 3-n: Various row Dollar Amounts, default hidden;

Set rows 2-n to toggle based on Row 1.
When you the report initially renders, Row 2 will be visible, Row 3n are not.  When you toggle, Row 2 will hide, row 3n will be visible.